# how to change status bar color in phonegap 3.4 in inappbrowser?

Tags: cordova, statusbar, inappbrowser

My current app is in phone gap 3.4. Can I control the status bar background colour in InAppBrowser? Any changes through status bar plugin is reflected on native pages but not on web?

Currently InAppBrowser shows its background colour on the status bar. Either I need to change the status bar colour on web or I want the InAppBrowser to start from the top of the page without leaving 20 pixel margin which will give me an iOS7 app look with status bar by default being transparent.

Answer (score 3):

There are many options you have customizing the status bar per cordova v 3.4

### Hide Status Bar:

- First (in xcode) click your project
- Then click the Resources folder to expose your .plist
- Once you located the .plist click the (+) Next to Information Property List
- Add this property View controller-based status bar appearance with value as NO

### Change Status Bar to Translucent:

- First (in xcode) click your project
- Find TARGETS, ckick on your project name under TARGETS
- Find Deployment Info then see the Status Bar Style drop down list of options

### Change Status Bar Background within confix.xml

- First (in xcode) click your project
- Find confix.xml
- Add these lines to the xml right before the

  < /widget >
  < preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#ff0000" />

### Add Status Bar Plugin To Cordova

- Within terminal.. cd into your project where cordova is located
- Run this command
  cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.statusbar
- Once the plugin is loaded you can then work with the plugin via the onDeviceReady function that fires when cordova has loaded.

Example:

```
onDeviceReady: function () {

  StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
  StatusBar.hide();
  App.phoneGapApp.receivedEvent('deviceready');
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: this works in native but not when i move from native to inappbrowser

Answer (score 1):

To change the colour of the status bar and navigation bar access the file `CDVInAppBrowser.m` (located in `${PROJECT_ROOT}/platforms/ios/${PROJECT_NAME}/Plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/CDVInAppBrowser.m`

**Status Bar:**

Change `greenColor` to any `UIColor`

```
- (void)createViews
{
    self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

**Navigation Bar**

Change `redColor` to any `UIColor`

```
- (void)createViews
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

**Status Bar Text Colour**

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    // White
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;

    // Or Black:
    // return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2018**

You can pass the required toolbar color in the options like this (red):

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'toolbar=yes,toolbarcolor=#FF0000');
```

Comment: toolbar != status bar

Comment: you are completely right; however, this did change the statusbar color of the in app browser popup window. If you want to change the status bar color use plugin: cordova-plugin-statusbar

Comment: just of curiosity - if you change color of status/tool bar what happens when you switch to night mode? I had issue where I could not keep that color, but night mode would switch to contrast color (black). I could only fix it by disabling night mode alltogether (in config.xml)